# JS Adding/Removing image from cell (toggle button)

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am looking for a way to add and remove an image in a cell.

I have the button assigned to this function but I can't seem to add it to the dynamic range. If I hardcode the column and row for testing it adds the image fine but then I can't figure out how to delete it.

```
function test() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var selection = sheet.getSelection();
  var ranges = selection.getActiveRangeList().getRanges();
  for (var i in ranges) {
    var data = ranges[i].getValues();
    for (var row in data) for (var col in data[row]) {
        var cell = data[row][col];
        if (cell == '') continue;                      // if empty --> go to next cell
        IF CELL CONTAINS IMAGE REMOVE IT
          continue;                                    // --> go to next cell
        } else {
          sheet.insertImage("URL", [col], [row], 125, 2); //Add image at col/row
        }
    }
    ranges[i].setValues(data);
  }
}
```

**Before button click**

[image: BEFORE CLICK]

**After button click**

[image: AFTER CLICK]

**Select new cells**

[image: SELECT NEW CELLS]

**After button click**

[image: AFTER BUTTON CLICK]

Comment: `insertImage` method puts the image on the cell. In this case, the image is not inserted in the cell. Is this the same as your goal? If you wanted to put the image on the cell, in order to remove the image on the cell, how about using the method of [remove() of Class Image](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/slides/image#remove)?

Comment: I can't add  the image in the cell as there is text, I wish I could but I don't think there is a way to have text with embedded image. so for now the image just gets put over the cell and it looks like it is in the cell. I was trying to research how to assign an ID to each image and delete them that way but no luck.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I understood that you are using the images on the cells. In that case, how about using "Title" and "Description" of "Alt Text" for each image? When these values are used, you can retrieve the specific images using the values with Google Apps Script. If this was not the direction you expect, I apologize.

Comment: I am completely open to play around with that. I just started my JS journey today so I am really struggling to get the syntax perfect. I was trying to find a way to add such parameters in insertImage and call them but wasn't having much luck. I will research into Title and Description. Maybe it is possible to assign an image to cells with the title being the range (Image22 would reflect 2nd column 2nd row and concatenate the variables of the selected cell to delete that image. Does any of that make sense? No idea how to begin...

Comment: Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, from your replying, I cannot understand your current situation and your current goal. Can you provide detailed information about them?

Comment: Of course. Example: Cell A1 and B1 are selected. When button is pressed images get added with title "11" and "21" (representing column and row). When button is selected again (with A1 and B1 selected), images "11" and "21" are deleted. Does that help at all?

Comment: Thank you for replying. I'm confusing your question. I apologize for my poor English skill again. So I would like to confirm your current goal. In your current goal, you want to add the title to the existing images on Google Spreadsheet and your goal is not to remove the images. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: Yes, that is correct. Except I would like to remove said images when button is selected again and images exist in selected cells. To 'toggle' on / off

Comment: Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for my poor English skill again. I cannot imagine your situation from `Except I would like to remove said images when button is selected again and images exist in selected cells. To 'toggle' on / off`. For example, can you provide the sample input and output situations you expect as the image? By this, I would like to try to understand it.

Comment: I have added images to illustrate goal.

Comment: Thank you for replying and providing more information. From your provided information, I proposed an answer. Could you please confirm it? If I misunderstood your question and that was not useful, I apologize.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your goal is as follows.

- When the script is run after the cells are selected, you want to put the image on the cell.
- When the image is not put on the cell, you want to put the image on the cell.
- When the image has already been put on the cell, you want to remove the image.
- When the cell value is empty, you don't want to do anything.

In this case, how about the following modified script?

#### Modified script:

```js
function test() {
  const url = "###"; // Please set your URL.

  const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  const ranges = sheet.getActiveRangeList().getRanges();
  let images = sheet.getImages();
  ranges.forEach(r => {
    const row = r.getRow();
    const col = r.getColumn();
    const numRows = r.getNumRows();
    const numCols = r.getNumColumns();
    for (let i = 0; i < numRows; i++) {
      for (let j = 0; j < numCols; j++) {
        if (sheet.getRange(row + i, col + j).isBlank()) continue;
        const image = images.filter(e => {
          const anchor = e.getAnchorCell();
          return anchor.getRow() == row + i && anchor.getColumn() == col + j;
        });
        if (image.length > 0) {
          image.forEach(e => e.remove());
          images = sheet.getImages();
        } else {
          sheet.insertImage(url, col + j, row + i, 125, 2);
        }
      }
    }
  });
}
```

- At first, please set your URL.
- When you use this script, please select the cells and run the script.
- When you run this script for the selected cells, the images are put on the cells which have no images, and the images are removed from the cells which have the images.
- In this case, the image on the cells can be checked using the method of getAnchorCell() of Class OverGridImage.

#### References:

- [getImages() of Class Sheet](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getImages())
- [getAnchorCell() of Class OverGridImage](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/over-grid-image#getanchorcell)

Comment: Thank you! This is exactly what I was looking for. Although it is very very slow it still does the job.

Comment: @Kevin P. Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. About the process cost, unfortunately, in the current stage, the images cannot be managed using Sheets API. Even when `sheet.getRange(row + i, col + j).isBlank()` is modified for comparing values which have already been retrieved at out of loop, the cost didn't change largely. So I think that image management might be the reason. When Sheets API is used and batchUpdate can be used, the cost will be low. So, how about reporting it to Google Issue Tracker as a future request? [Ref](https://developers.google.com/issue-tracker)